# Frames grabbed from UDP H264 stream with ffmpeg are gray/distorded

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, h.264, javacv

I am grabbing frames from a udp h264 stream with Javacv's FFMPEG on windows, and putting them into a JavaFX imageview. The problem is that most of the image isn't received well (it is gray, distored...) :

[image: The JavaFX imageview result]

I used to have the same problem before and I made it work by using flush on the frame grabber after each frame, but I forgot to save my work and lost it, and this time the correction doesn't work.

Here's the part where i configure/launch FFMPEG :

```
        final Java2DFrameConverter converter = new Java2DFrameConverter();

        // Show drone camera
        FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("udp://227.0.0.1:2200");

        grabber.setFrameRate(_frameRate);
        grabber.setFormat(_format);
        grabber.setVideoBitrate(25000000);
        grabber.setVideoOption("preset", "ultrafast");
        grabber.setNumBuffers(0);

        grabber.start();

        // Grab frames as long as the thread is running
        while(_running){
               final Frame frame = grabber.grab();
               if (frame != null) {
                   final BufferedImage bufferedImage = converter.convert(frame);
                   if (bufferedImage != null) {
                         _cameraView.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null));
                   }
                }
                Thread.sleep( 1000 / _frameRate );// don't grab frames faster than they are provided
                grabber.flush();
        }
        _grabber.close();
```

_format is "h264" and _frameRate is 30.

Also, the system is flooded with prints like these (I'm not sure they are related to the problem though) :

```
[h264 @ 00000000869c0a80] Invalid NAL unit 4, skipping.
[h264 @ 00000000869c0a80] Invalid NAL unit 4, skipping.
[h264 @ 00000000869c0a80] Invalid NAL unit 4, skipping.
[h264 @ 00000000869c0a80] Reference 6 >= 4
[h264 @ 00000000869c0a80] error while decoding MB 115 14, bytestream 1979
[h264 @ 00000000869c0a80] concealing 6414 DC, 6414 AC, 6414 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0000000078f81180] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000000078f81180] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000000078f81180] concealing 4811 DC, 4811 AC, 4811 MV errors in B frame
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work anymore

Comment: The problem is lost packets on the network, but you only post image code. Show the network code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work, but sadly it doesn't really answers the problem :

I removed the following configuration lines :

```
grabber.setFrameRate(_frameRate);
grabber.setFormat(_format);
grabber.setVideoBitrate(25000000);
grabber.setVideoOption("preset", "ultrafast");
grabber.setNumBuffers(0);
```

I also removed the flushing lines and the thread sleep which apparently weren't necessary :

```
Thread.sleep( 1000 / _frameRate );// don't grab frames faster than they are provided
grabber.flush();
```

And it worked...